# Which is the better way to query sql table for different input combinations

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, case

I am working on Stored Procedure in SQL 2008. I have to return the rows of a table based on different input combinations (around 17 combinations). 5 parameters are passed as i/p to this sp.

I started writing the SP checking in this way

```
DECLARE @varDynamicQuery    VARCHAR(255)

SET @varDynamicQuery = 'SELECT Name, Address, PhoneDetails 
                        FROM SuperUserDetails WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE '
    /* 
    Combi 1
    Input       -       Parameter       -       Output      -       Condition
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UID                 @in_varUID              TableRows           None                    

    */
    IF(@in_varUID IS NOT NULL AND @in_varUID <> '')
    BEGIN

        SET @varDynamicQuery = @varDynamicQuery + 'UID = '''+@in_varUID+''''

    EXEC (@varDynamicQuery)
    END

    /* 
    Combi 2
    Input       -       Parameter       -       Output      -       Condition
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Address             @in_varAddr             TableRows           None                    

    */
    IF(@in_varAddr IS NOT NULL AND @in_varAddr <> '')
    BEGIN

        SET @varDynamicQuery = @varDynamicQuery + 'UID = '''+@in_varAddr+''''

    EXEC (@varDynamicQuery)
    END

    /* 
    Combi 3
    Input       -       Parameter       -       Output      -       Condition
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UID                 @in_varUID              TableRows           None    
    Address             @in_varAddr                                 

    */
    IF( (@in_varUID  IS NOT NULL AND @in_varUID  <> '') AND(@in_varAddr IS NOT NULL AND @in_varAddr <> '') )
    BEGIN

        SET @varDynamicQuery = @varDynamicQuery + 'UID = '''+@in_varUID+''' AND Address = ''''+@in_varAddr+'''

    EXEC (@varDynamicQuery)
    END
```

But, I am sure, a better way than this. As writing 17 combinations is not a good way.

If it better to write this using CASE statements?

The list of combinations are,(only 6 are shown) The input parameters to Sp are also listed.

> Input Params     C1     C2     C3     C4     C5     C6
>
> UID              Y      N      N      N      N      N
>
> Address          N      Y      N      N      Y      Y
>
> PhoneDetails     N      N      Y      Y      Y      N
>
> CreatedOn        Y      Y      N      Y      Y      Y
>
> LastDate         Y      Y      N      N      N      Y

Please advice me on this.

Thanks
Ramm

Comment: Could you add in the base query itself please? That would help suggest alternatives.

Comment: @shree.pat18, I didnt get your question. Are you asking me for entire Select Stmt used for fetching records from table? Thanks

Comment: any suggestions please .. !!!